# hide the "modified" "modified by" from web-parts

Tags: web-part, list-view, view, modified

Is there a way to hide the "modified" and "modified from" from listing-webparts?
I already created a new view and set it as the standard/default view.
In this view I didn't check the boxes so it shouldn't be showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Edit web part. Then click Edit the current view. Then Uncheck the modified and modified by. This will hide your columns.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that there are seperate view settings.
So you have to do this for every webpart?
For what do you use these listview settings then if they don't overwrite the web-part ones?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the page and edit the web part. On the right hand side of the page **edit the current view** and deselect *modified* and *modified by* checkboxes. Save view, save web part, save page and publish (if applicable).

[image]